# How to find date among different strings and convert it to correct date format?

Tags: c#, angularjs

I have one problem,

I am using angularjs for the front end, so I have date picker in the directive.

```
<input  " + required + "  id='" + elementName + "' name='" + elementName + "' ng-model='question.answer.SelectedAnswer' readonly='' ng-click='opened=!opened' type='text' placeholder='Date'   datepicker-popup='" + format + "' is-open='opened' min-date='minDate' datepicker-options='dateOptions' close-text='Close' />
```

when I select a date like 17-6-1992 and sending it to DB , it's saving in DB like 
2016-06-16T18:30:00.000Z instead of 17-6-1992, but when I get it back from DB I am getting it as 2016-06-16T18:30:00.000Z, but while showing it in the same input field its coming like 17-6-1992.

basically in DB its saving as the previous date but in UI its showing the correct.
why this issue is coming.

now I want to export this date as CSV in the controller. in CSV file the result coming as 2016-06-16T18:30:00.000Z . instead of this in CSV also I want to show what is showing in UI as I mentioned above.

in CSV file it should be like 17-6-1992, no date needed.

```
string answerString = string.Join(",", answers.Where(i => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i.Answer) == false).Select(j => j.Answer).ToArray());
```

this is what I am using to write CSV file, I will catch all answers as the string and print it.  these answers contains that date , so I want to find which is in date format among answers and need to convert it to proper date format.

Comment: change your db field to date only rather than datetime

Comment: Check if you can convert time to non-UTC - if C# use -TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc Method (DateTime, TimeZoneInfo) or for vice versa -
DateTime.ToUniversalTime Method ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Z" is kind of a unique case for DateTimes. The literal "Z" is actually part of the ISO 8601 datetime standard for UTC times. When "Z" (Zulu) is added on the end of a time, it indicates that that time is UTC, so really the literal Z is part of the time. This probably creates a few problems for the date format library in .NET, since it's actually a literal, rather than a format specifier.

You can Simply use $filter in angular to filter the date, Here is the [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/YUeKCYrRcjQRzU8khcm4?p=preview)

Sample code are as follows

Script.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $filter) {
    var jsonvalue = '2016-06-16T18:30:00.000Z';
    $scope.time = new Date(jsonvalue);
    $scope.parsed = $filter('date')($scope.time, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <h1>Actual Parsed Date</h1>
      <p>{{parsed}}</p>
  <h1>With Time</h1>
    <p>{{time | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}</p>
     <h1>WithOut Time</h1>
      <p>{{time | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is i dont want it to be converted in angularjs side, i want it tobe converted in C# side for file creation.